# XXD and Grep recursively in a directory of files

Tags: linux, bash

I have a question, i know it is possible to perform XXD -u file | grep "ABCD"
however is it possible to perform XXD -u directory? then grep the "ABCD"?

Comment: Are you asking if you can run `xxd` on a directory directly? `xxd -u dir/`? If not, what is the question?

Comment: I am asking are there any ways to perform XXD -u directory | grep "ABCD"    or any other alternative solutions?

Comment: Did you try it? How did the result not do what you expected? *What are you trying to achieve* ([not the commands, but the end result](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem))? Are you trying to find a file/line containing a specific hex string, or convert a specific text string to hex, or something else?

Comment: I am trying to find a file containing a specific hex string

Comment: Are there directories within that directory? Or just files? It looks like xxd only operates on one file at a time so you'll need a loop (which is likely true if you want to be able to report which file matched easily).

Comment: just files, how do i perform a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

FILES=/FILEPATH/*
for f in $FILES
do
   echo "PROCESSING $f FILES"
   echo "-------------------"
   XXD -u $f | grep ABCD
   echo "-------------------"
done
```